# DNS returning a list of addresses

Tags: networking, dns, network-programming

So, my apologies if my question in not clear, I have limited knowledge in DNS and it is possible my wording is incorrect.

A colleague, once explained me new DNS can return several ip for one host. I saw it was indeed possible with round robin, but the way I understood was to delegate the task of choosing which ip to the client. At the same time, it was possible to add a priority, or weighting to the response.
The purpose behind this was to have a first level load balancing between different zones.

I can not find more information about this, but I believe the terminology I use is incorrect.

Could you tell me more about this, or I got confused by his explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Round Robin DNS

Round Robin DNS is a basic form of load balancing. [Check out the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

For an excellent explanation of how to use Round Robin DNS in a practical context see [AWS's tutorial on using RRDNS with Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted)

Comment: I dont' have enough rep to post this additional URL:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring-options.html#dns-failover-weighted-rrsets